# Summernote - textarea behind toolbar

Tags: css, laravel, summernote

I use summernote in a Laravel application.

```
               <div id="editIssue" style="display: none">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('projects.issues.update', $issue)}}" method="put">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 text-right control-label col-form-label">Title*</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="title" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{$issue->title}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 text-right control-label col-form-label">Description</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group m-b-0">
                            <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light m-t-10">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

I open the div by using jquery button with function show/hide.

When i open the div, the content text of summernote is behind the toolbar. When i scroll or resize the window, the content text is shown correctly.

When i remove `style="display: none"` the text is shown correctly.

Is there any conflict with summernote and show/hide div?

Before scroll:

[image]

After scroll:

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same toolbar overlapping issue. Similar to the issue in your question, my summernote text area is hidden until a div is displayed using a css/javascript tab library. I added a 50px !important padding top to the .note-editable class to resolve this issue. `.note-editable {height: 50vh; padding-top: 50px !important;}` of course this css must be placed after the summernote.css is loaded to the page.

Answer (score 3):

We found out that when scrolling before opening the summernote textarea some css was added to the toolbar and the toolbar-wrapper. To fix this I just added the following code to remove the css that was added.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $('.note-toolbar-wrapper').removeAttr('style');    
    $('.note-toolbar').removeAttr('style');
})
```

Comment: This works, but it seems that you had the opposite case, of the description showing behind the toolbar AFTER you scroll, opposed to before you scroll in your modal

Answer (score 2):

This is available in Summernote by default now. You can control it by setting the `followingToolbar` boolean in the options.

```
$('#description').summernote({
        followingToolbar: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Init the summernote on toggle:

```
        $('#buttonEditIssue').click(function () {
        $('#showIssue').hide()
        $('#editIssue').show()
        $('#description').summernote({
            placeholder: 'Enter your description',
            tabsize: 2,
            height: 150,
            dialogsInBody: true,
            toolbar: [
                ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
                ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['height', ['height']]
            ]
        });

    })
```